# NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, shiro

The issue was caused by one of the dependencies in my pom.xml [cxf-bundle-jaxrs] which internally uses lower version of slf4j. I managed to resolve this issue by upgrading this dependency to the latest release. Thanks everyone.

I'm trying to add Apache Shiro to my CXF Spring web application. When I start up my tomcat 7 I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
at org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor.<clinit>(LifecycleBeanPostProcessor.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
... 25 more
```

and my pom.xml for shiro and slf4j is

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried every possible solution by googling, but no luck.

Answer (score 24):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
```

This means that you have the class `StaticLoggerBinder` in your classpath.
But the class of your classpath does not have the method `getSingleton()`

This usually happens when you have dependencies that both use the same transitive dependency. This means that 2 of your dependencies (or your app, and a transitive dependency) are both using SLF4J internally with different versions. But your app can only use a single version of the class at the same time so it has to choose (don't know the rules here... random?)

To solve the problem, you usually need to do a `mvn dependency:tree` to see which are using different versions of SLF4J.

The solution is often to use a maven dependency exclusion on the lowest version. Libraries like SLF4J tend to be retrocompatible which means newer versions keep adding more features. Sometimes, a method is removed and then you have to keep the old library version, and pray. If this doesn't work there are still some options, like [JarJar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/)

But for logging libraries it's sometimes a bit different, so my explaination is for general purpose, but it's probable you do not use the right logging library dependencies because they have very special packagings which are not always easy to understand :)

---

Check what I found for you:

- https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/SLF4J_1.5.5/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.java
- https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/SLF4J_1.5.6/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.java

The `getSingleton()` method appeared at version 1.5.6, so it is very probable that you have a library that uses an SLF4J version older that 1.5.6 :) You just need to exclude it with a maven exclusion (and pray).

---

Edit: you should try:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Better, if you have a multimodule maven project with a parent pom you can use this with maven dependencyManagement xml node.

Comment: After I ran `mvn dependency:tree` here are some new clues: I have cxf-bundle-jaxrs 2.2 which internally uses `org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.3.1:runtime`  How can I use depedency exclusion to solve this issue? -Thanks

Comment: @KunXia this is explained on maven website but I edited my answer. I can't be sure of the solution unless you post your complete dependencies and the dependency:tree output

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to resolve this issue by upgrading the cxf-bundle-jaxrs to the latest release. My bad I should post the full pom.xml. Will update my question with solution.:)

Comment: You should also use dependency management section to prevent such kind of issues.

Comment: @SebastienLorber - what a great explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to include this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I included the above dependency but still got the same error.`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: You need to make sure that the slf4j versions are all the same.  Update `slf4j-api` to 1.7.5 or downgrade `slf4j-log4j12` to 1.6.1

Answer (score 2):

Something seems to be not compatible with those sl4j-api and log4j versions.
[Try this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j) and find the correct and compatible dependencies and use them.

May be you should try the following combination,

> SLF4J API Module  1.7.5       The slf4j API
>
> SLF4J LOG4J-12 Binding    1.7.5       SLF4J LOG4J-12 Binding

Or, if you are planning to use version 1.6.1

```
 <!-- slf4j-log4j -->       
    <dependency>            
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>          
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>     
          <version>1.6.1</version>      
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I have tried both and got the same error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;`

Answer (score 2):

Adding this dependency solved the issue for me

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```