# Spring error (org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException)

Tags: spring

Im new using Spring, and I have a problem when run my webbapp. Im using a Jboss Server and NetBeans

It's the error:

```
13:07:19,692 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.atlantis.atencioncliente.service.impl.HibernateDao.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [persistence-beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
```

FOLLOW THE ERROR

Here the employeeDao interface:

```
package com.atlantis.atencioncliente.service.dao;

import com.atlantis.atencioncliente.domain.Employee;
import com.atlantis.atencioncliente.service.GenericDao;

/**
 * DAO of employee.
 */
public interface EmployeeDao extends GenericDao<Employee, Long> {

/**
 * Tries to remove employee from the system.
 * @param employee Employee to remove
 * @return {@code true} if employee is not assigned to any task
 * or timesheet. Else {@code false}.
 */
boolean removeEmployee(Employee employee);

}
```

Here Hibernate.dao

```
package com.atlantis.atencioncliente.service.impl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.atlantis.atencioncliente.service.GenericDao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Basic DAO operations dependent with Hibernate's specific classes
 * @see SessionFactory
 */
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public class HibernateDao<E, K extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<E, K> {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
protected Class<? extends E> daoType;

public HibernateDao() {
    daoType = (Class<E>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                    .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

protected Session currentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Override
public void add(E entity) {
    currentSession().save(entity);
}

@Override
public void update(E entity) {
    currentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
}

@Override
public void remove(E entity) {
    currentSession().delete(entity);
}

@Override
public E find(K key) {
    return (E) currentSession().get(daoType, key);
}

@Override
public List<E> list() {
    return currentSession().createCriteria(daoType).list();
}
}
```

And here persistence-bean.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx


http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<!-- we can use annotations -->
<context:annotation-config />  

<!-- package to look for annotated classes -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.atlantis.atencioncliente.service.impl" />

<!-- we will manage transactions with annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- data source for our database -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"
        value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://SBPORTALPRE/atclientepre" />
    <property name="username" value="atcliuser" />
    <property name="password" value="atclipass" />
</bean>

<!-- configure hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses" >
        <list>
            <value>com.atlantis.atencioncliente.domain.Employee</value>
            <value>com.atlantis.atencioncliente.domain.Manager</value>
            <value>com.atlantis.atencioncliente.domain.Task</value>
            <value>com.atlantis.atencioncliente.domain.Timesheet</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>   
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
<constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Finally, here is my pom.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.atlantis</groupId>
<artifactId>com.atlantis</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>atencioncliente</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
        <version>1.5.5</version> 
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId> 
        <version>1.5.5</version> 
        <scope>runtime</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> 
        <version>1.5.5</version> 
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
               <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
           </exclusion>                     
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!--  Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j 
  --> 
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId> 
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId> 
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any suggest? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add jar file in your build path..

 and check all jars configured properly.....

Comment: The problem is with the slf4j dependency in your project. What do you use for building, Maven or something else?

Comment: Maven. I have add slf4j dependencies, but the error persist

Comment: Please post your pom.xml to investigate

Comment: I have added my pom.XML in the main post

Comment: Sounds for me like this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755893/nosuchmethoderror-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-getsingleton

Comment: More interesting information. My project run at TOMCAT, the fail only affect with JBoss. 

But if I add slf4j dependencies, the project dont run at TOMCAT...

Comment: @markusw, I have revised the post, In the dependencies graph, I located a warning (conflict of versions). I have exclude to avoid the conflict, but the error persist....