# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tags, log4j, slf4j

Spring Boot Application

I am making a Tag Reader Application where am keep Getting This issue

Note: i am not using any Property file input

***This my Simple Spring boot application***

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RfidReaderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RfidReaderApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

***Pom.xml ***

This pom configursation that i am using to build project and also have one external jar for OctaneSDKJava because it not reader OctaneSDKJava jar form pom so i added externally

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Amazin.RFID.Reader</groupId>
    <artifactId>RFID-Reader</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RFID-Reader</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.octane</groupId>
            <artifactId>OctaneSDKJava</artifactId>
            <version>1.32.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

[image]

***Error Msg that i am getting***

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:285)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:220)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.Amazin.RFID.Reader.RfidReaderApplication.main(RfidReaderApplication.java:10)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737992/noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder)

Comment: so can i find where is duplicating  can you please tell me

Comment: Try one of the solutions in the answers

Comment: @harkeshkumar Can you give a screenshot of your project structure ?

Answer (score 0):

As shown through [the post linked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737992/noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder), you are possibly missing some SLF4J dependencies. Another possibility, however, is that your dependencies actually have different versions of SLF4J, but since only one can be used there is a clash. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755893/nosuchmethoderror-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-getsingleton) as well.

I would recommend explicitly using `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` since you are using spring boot and going from there.